# find position of a list term in gdb

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm wondering if it is possible, within a debugging session, to tell gdb to go over all the terms of an std::vector and print out the indexes of those that satisfy a certain condition. In my case I have vector, and I would like to know which of the terms are negative. 
I am well aware that this can be accomplished using conditional breakpoints, but for that I would have to rerun the program and place the breakpoint in the position where the vector is initialized, but it's less convenient.

Comment: You can call a function within the debugger that would not otherwise be called in the execution of the code.  Just write an appropriate function and call it on your vector.

Comment: That's a good idea, but this also means I would have to restart the debugging session every time I would have to add a new functionality, and I am looking for something more dynamical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of doing what you are asking for with plain gdb. The debugger does not have a language in which you can run arbitrary queries. That being said, the debugger does have support (at least not ancient versions) to load python scripts that will interact with data.

You can define scripts in the gdb command line, or else you can define them in files and load them from the command line.